# How to avoid ruining the heel of shoes

Tags: shoes, repair

On the inside of my shoes I often get this issue:

[image]

Can i fix it without going to a shoe repair? would it be expensive to fix and how to avoid it in the future? It happens to all my shoes...

Comment: What exactly is this? (The image is not entirely clear) Is the fabric/leather on the inside actually damaged or is it just wrinkled? How long does it take for a new pair of shoes to have this issue? Is it on both sides or just one side?

Comment: @Elmy it is actually damaged, part of it is cut. it takes 10-12 months for this issue to appear. both sides have the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have that problem too, here is how I fix it:

I obtain a small piece of leather that is smooth on one side and rough on the other. I cut it to cover the damaged zone plus some overlap. I then use *contact glue* on the rough side to glue this patch into the shoe (following the directions on the glue tube).

You can get small scraps of leather for this purpose inexpensively at an upholstery shop that repairs chairs and car seats using leather.

In this way I have been able to get many years of use out of a shoe where the leather in the heel has started to break as in your case.

Comment: ah yes, that's a good idea to patch it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Avoid the issue**

Use a shoe horn to avoid causing this damage to the shoe "counters" at the rear of the shoe.

The smooth concave curve of the horn base lets your foot heel slide into the base of the shoe without repeatedly catching on the edge of the shoe.